# Speed of sound in a solid calculated theoretically

Tags: acoustics, speed, solid-mechanics, ultrasound

I am trying to find theoretically precise values of the speed of sound in various solid materials. I have found the CRC Handbook of Chemistry and Physics with a table of values with no uncertainties reported, I don't know if I should interpret this as if these values are theoretical, or as if they just did not bother to state the uncertainties.  https://hbcp.chemnetbase.com/faces/contents/InteractiveTable.xhtml

I also know that it would in theory be possible to compute the longitudinal speed of sound by using $\sqrt{\frac{K+\frac{4}{3}G}{\rho}}$ with K,G,$\rho$ being bulk modulus, shear modulus, and density. Is this how they calculated it? if not, is there any database where I can find the information I'm looking for?

Comment: The table that you are sharing is behind a paywall.

Answer (score 1):

What most people call speed of sound in solids is the following

$$c = \sqrt{\frac{E}{\rho}}\, $$

that is speed of a wave propagating in a slender bar. This value is between the speed of shear and longitudinal waves.

You normally don't find these values with uncertainties because they are used as reference values. In an application that requires a precision where these uncertainties matter you need to measure the values of the materials you are using.

I have a database for some solids [here](https://github.com/nicoguaro/material_database/tree/master/materials). I have intervals in the case of [common materials](https://github.com/nicoguaro/material_database/blob/master/materials/common_materials.tsv), but this list does not have Poisson ratios, so you won't be able to use it to compute speeds. Also, I present there the elastic properties for some anisotropic materials, in that case the speeds are not constant and depend on the relative orientation betwee the propagation direction and the material.